# google custom search api zip code filter

Tags: google-custom-search

I am integrating google custom search api in an application, I need to add a state/city filter or zip code filter. i have studied the google custom search api documentation.

Following is the link https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

There is a "gl" parameter for country in the optional but i need to filter on state,city or zip code.

Comment: There was an issue when you started your bounty that prevented your question from being viewed.  I've refunded your bounty so you can start it again, if you like.  Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Abuzer Firdousi - Did you solve this problem?